# Printing values of all fields in a C++ structure

Tags: c++, visual-c++, structure

Consider a simple structure:

```
struct abc  
{  
    int a;  
    char b;  
}
```

I got some value in a variable defined as its structure, and now I want to print the below.

```
*a = [some value]  
b = [some character]*
```

What is the best way to achieve this for an arbitrary structure without having to write a dump...(...) function for each of the structure I encounter?

Comment: Well, after writing this question, I randomly did google and found below discussion
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878285/iterate-over-struct-easily-display-struct-fields-and-values-in-a-richedit-box

I think that answers all my doubts. Thanks everyone for answer though.

Answer (score 30):

It seems you already found the solution, but I'll expand a bit.

What you are calling for is called `Reflection`, i.e. the ability for an object to describe itself.

Most languages can implement reflection thanks to metadata. In Python for example, the functions and attributes of an object are stored in a dictionary element.

C++ does not have any native reflection system unlike C# or Java, which prevents (for example) this kind of automatic printing / serialization or deserialization.

However, C++ has very powerful metaprogramming support which allows us (through the use of templates) to emulate reflection (at compile-time). This is usually done using [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html), a library meant for crossing over from compile-time to run-time.

As the example demonstrated in your link, the [`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html) macro allows you to take a standard `struct` and give it the required interface to be treated as a Fusion.Sequence.

Another example would be to use [`Fusion.Vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/vector.html) or [`Fusion.Map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/map.html) to store the attributes of the class and then expose this Sequence to automatic print/serialization/deserialization methods.

There is a limitation to this system however: Metaprogramming does not mesh well with OO-programming.

```
struct Base { char a; };            // Adapt
struct Derived: Base { char b; };   // Adapt

void print(Base const& b) { boost::fusion::for_each<Base>(b, Print()); }
```

will only print the member of `Base` (here `a`). When using polymorphism, you need to use `virtual` methods at one point or another :)

Comment: I like the fusion.adapt.struct solution. [Asked specifically how to descend into nested struct fields and got it all working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102144/362754).

Answer (score 3):

You need "reflection" to do this. Reflection is not provided natively in C++, or only for minimal informations (type ids/names).

There are libraries (like [CAMP](https://github.com/tegesoft/camp)) that implement reflection features, so if you REALLY need reflection you should use one.

Answer (score 2):

With C++17 (perhaps even C++14), and some crazy Russian hacks - it can be partially done. That is, you can print the types values in sequence, but you can't get the field names.

The relevant library is Antony Polukhin's ["magic_get"](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get). Specifically, it offers a "for each field" iteration [mechanism](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get/blob/develop/test/precise/for_each_field.cpp), which takes a templated lambda with `auto` parameter type. Example:

```
struct simple {
    int a;
    char b;
    short d;
};

simple x {42, 'a', 3};
std::stringstream ss;

boost::pfr::for_each_field(
    x,
    [&ss](auto&& val) {
        ss << val << ' ';
    }
);
```

<sub>Answer migrated from a related/duplicate question - since somehow nobody mentioned this here.</sub>

Comment: boost::pfr::for_each_field_with_name

Comment: the gpt tell us

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one, not in C++. Tough luck.

Comment: There are various ways to have this: template metaprogramming, parsing or class generation with an external tool. Don't forget many things are possible with computers, though perhaps not easily or in the way you thought it should be.

Comment: [There are reflection libraries](https://github.com/rttrorg/rttr), and reflection is on its way into the standard. This answer is now out of date

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++ in .NET, you can potentially use the [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) stuff to look at the innards of your structure. Unmanaged C++ rarely, if ever, stores that kind of metadata about objects, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct abc  
{  
    int a;  
    char b;  
};
void display(abc myStruct){
   cout << "struct abc {"<< endl;
   cout << abc.a << endl;
   cout << abc.b << endl;
   cout << "}" << endl;
}
int main(){
    abc myStruct
    display(myStruct);
}
```

reflection is only required when the structs will be user defined and not by you and you are not sure about the internal structure of the struct.