# Struct Element Names to Cout?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can I print the element names of a structure in C++?

Example: If I have the structure in my code as

```
struct Info {
uint8_t ID;
uint8_t Weight;
uint8_t Time[3];
}
```

I want my console to print the text below without hard-coding them.
I want it to be extracted from the struct. Is this possible?

> ID, Weight, Time0, Time1, Time2

Note: not the value of ID or what not. I would want the console to print the words "ID, Weight... etc". It will be used as field names for a file.

Comment: Just checking, should this be retagged as C code?

Comment: Keyword is reflection. You may either implement it yourself or seek for a library. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/88215/4123703

Comment: @JVApen No, I am working on c++ but my header files are formatted that way, so i have the example struct like that :)

Comment: @Nard Go through this thread: [visual c++ - Printing values of all fields in a C++ structure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758937/printing-values-of-all-fields-in-a-c-structure).

Comment: @Nard I would recommend writing `struct Name { int ID; .. };` instead if you are using c++. I know sufficient professional C++ programmers that can't read your code

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are identifiers, after compilation they do not exist in the compiled executable.  You cannot print them in a regular C++ application.

But if you want to create the output yourself it would look like this:

```
struct Info {
    uint8_t ID;
    uint8_t Weight;
    uint8_t Time[3];
};

int main()
{

    Info infoObj;
    infoObj.ID = 1;

    std::cout << "infoObj.ID = " << infoObj.ID << std::endl;

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to Hard Code the variable name. So there is no way to get the variable names?

Comment: @Nard no, not using regular C++